# how can I enable scrollbars on the WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

When I run the following **Northwind WPF Toolkit Datagrid** code from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGrid.aspx), I get a datagrid, but there are **no scrollbars** and hence the user can only see part of the datagrid. I am using the newest version March 2009.

**What do I need to specify so that the WPF Datagrid has scrollbars?**

I tried putting the datagrid in a ScrollViewer but that didn't help.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid566.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="Window1" Height="600" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**code-behind:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using TestDataGrid566.Model;

namespace TestDataGrid566
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var customers = from c in db.Customers
                            select c;
            TheDataGrid.ItemsSource = customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Datagrid - Not showing any Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015890/wpf-datagrid-not-showing-any-scrollbar)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Put the `DataGrid` in a `Grid`, `DockPanel`, `ContentControl` or directly in the `Window`. A vertically-oriented `StackPanel` will give its children whatever vertical space they ask for - even if that means it is rendered out of view.

Comment: To add to this, a `HeaderedContentControl` is implemented internally with a `StackPanel` which will cause a `DataGrid` to behave in a manner inconsistent with the `ContentControl`.

Comment: I thought this advice was rubbish for hours, until I finally spotted the StackPanel tag lurking unseen at the top of my XAML. Thanks!

Comment: Also having a vertically-oriented Stackpanel will hinder Virtualization and affect application performance.

Comment: Also, if the DataGrid is placed in a Grid Row, do not use "Auto", as this will allow the datagrid to expand off the screen--without scrollbars. To show scroll bars, a size must be explicitly given to the DataGrid -- as in * or a number.

Comment: Hi @kiran , my name is also kiran :D

Answer (score 63):

WPF4

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
</DataGrid>
```

with : `<ColumnDefinition Width="350" />` & `<RowDefinition Height="300" />` works fine.

Scrollbars don't show with `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />` & `<RowDefinition Height="300" />`.

Also works fine with: `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` & `<RowDefinition Height="300" />` 
in the case where this is nested within an outer `<Grid>`.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten `ScrollViewer` is an attached property.

Answer (score 26):

If any of the parent containers `RowDefinition` Height set to `"Auto"` also stoppers for scrollbars

Alternatively you may set Height "*"

Which happened in my case.

Answer (score 23):

Adding `MaxHeight` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` on the `DataGrid` solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is effective. Solved my issue perfectly. Thanks~

Comment: Best answer in my humble opinion.

Comment: The most concise, working and valuable answer

Answer (score 4):

Add  grid with defined height and width for columns and rows. Then add `ScrollViewer` and inside it add the dataGrid.

Comment: If you prefer to keep the StackPanel, you can. Just define the height of the DataGrid. There is no need to enclose in ScrollViewer because then you would get 2 scroll bars which is probably not what you want. `<StackPanel><DataGrid Height="300"/></StackPanel>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to set `MaxHeight` and replace `IsEnabled="False"` by `IsReadOnly="True"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
The key is to use * as Row height.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tabItem">
                <TabItem x:Name="ta" 
                        Header="List of all Clients">
                        <DataGrid Name="clientsgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="2" 
                         ></DataGrid>
                </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    
    </Grid>
```

Comment: i don't know why a simple solution like this has been down voted - i can confirm, this simple (without bla bla and complex stuff) works perfectly for me - thanks!

Comment: @ChristianCasutt Because just by looking at it, it's more likely that the TabItem is affecting the outcome.  When I use * for the height on my row that contains a datagrid, it doesn't work.