# How to make data grid autoscrolling?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

After adding some other elements in the Grid, I found my data grid is no longer auto scrolling.
I want to know how to make Data grid autoscrolling in any case.

Comment: What did you mean by autoscrolling ? Did you mean that he scrollbars no longer appear ? Some code will helpful to identify the actual problem

Comment: No code involved. After adding some elements, I found data grid can no longer scroll any more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the below link and see if it solves your problem

[how can I enable scrollbars on the WPF Datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673516/how-can-i-enable-scrollbars-on-the-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: this link just talks about adding scrollbars, not automatically scrolling.